# on key press textbox not working properly

Tags: c#

if i enter 10 digits first time it takes 10 digits but if i clear textbox1 using backspace and enter again it takes only 9 digits. it should take 10 digits because i have set textbox1.maxlength=9 means it should count 10 digits(0 to 9).

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.KeyChar != '\b' && textBox1.Text.Trim().Length > 9)
        {

            e.Handled = true;
            MessageBox.Show("You can't enter more than ten digits...");
            textBox1.MaxLength = 9;
        }
}
```

Comment: It will count to 10 only if MaxLength is set to 9. If you set it to 9, it will count upto 9 digits only. Which means 0 to 8

Comment: `MaxLength` has nothing to do with counting digits. it is to do with the length of the string, Your question is unclear

Comment: Few things to be aware: 1) if MaxLength was 10 before you typed 10 "digits" then you'll decrease it to 9 after such edit. 2) You're not working with "digits" but with "code units". If user enters "è" (just for example) it will consume two System.Char (the _unit of measure_ of .NET strings length). 3) KeyPress handling will mess-up with many/most IME.

Comment: Why don't you use `MaskedTextBox` instead of ordinary `TextBox`?

Comment: @HarveySpecter I guess you wanted to write "It will count to 10 only if MaxLength is set to 10. If you set it to 9, it will count up to 9 character only. Which means 0 to 8"

Comment: Are you copy pasting a 10 digit string or manually typing one digit after the other ? If you are doing the first option, then it will take 10 digits at first and not afterwards.

Comment: @Bayeni - Yes ! Thanks for identifying that. :)

Comment: Sayse length of the string is reduced by one when i clear textbox1 with backspace

Comment: Mahaveer, its reduced the second your if statement condition is reached, the backspace isn't the issue

Comment: @HarveySpecter i am manually typing one digit after the other

Answer (score 0):

MaxLength is the literal amount of characters, i.e. a MaxLength of 9 has an index ranging from 0-8. Set MaxLength to 10.

Comment: Save yourself some energy. Make a good habit of reading comments. :)

Comment: This should really be a comment, it doesn't solve the "problem" the op is having, but then I don't know exactly what their problem is

Comment: Jacob according to you a MaxLength of 9 has digits from 0-8. than how it takes 10 digits when i enter digits first time

Comment: Edited it to answer the question as I interpreted it.

Comment: @Mahaveer Because you're setting the MaxLength in the wrong place,  set the MaxLength of the text box in its properties.

Answer (score 0):

MaxLength is used for counting the literal amount of characters within a string, therefore setting MaxLength to 9, would count 0-8, as 0 counts as a literal character.

Your solution would be to set MaxLength to 10.

Comment: This is just plagiarism of Jacob's answer

Comment: @Sayse I'm sorry, I was writing it at the time so the page didn't refresh for me to see his answer

Comment: @Sayse it's far from a word for word copy... don't jump the gun, the reason it's similar it's because it's the answer to the question and we both explained the function of MaxLength and explained why setting it to 9 would count how it did.